# SecAst: Failing to Ban IP ''

Tags: security, asterisk, sip, intrusion-detection

To Generation D:

This was the setup at time this issue was observed: secast-1.0.1.0-x86_64-ub12 on Ubuntu 12.04.4 Server LTS with Asterisk 11.10.2.

The following events were captured and observed in the /var/log/secast after leaving seacast (build secast-1.0.1.0-x86_64-ub12) running:

```
Sun Jun 22 14:22:45 2014, 00001403, D, Asterisk, IP '' added to watch list
Sun Jun 22 14:22:45 2014, 00000510, I, Asterisk, Detected potential intrustion attempt by username '%40102' at IP '' using protocol 'SIP' through security log '/var/log/asterisk/messages'
Sun Jun 22 14:23:05 2014, 00001402, D, Asterisk, IP '' on IP watch list with 2 potential intrusion attempts
Sun Jun 22 14:23:05 2014, 00000510, I, Asterisk, Detected potential intrustion attempt by username '%40102' at IP '' using protocol 'SIP' through security log '/var/log/asterisk/messages'
Sun Jun 22 14:23:07 2014, 00001402, D, Asterisk, IP '' on IP watch list with 3 potential intrusion attempts
Sun Jun 22 14:23:07 2014, 00000510, I, Asterisk, Detected potential intrustion attempt by username '%40' at IP '' using protocol 'SIP' through security log '/var/log/asterisk/messages'
Sun Jun 22 14:23:27 2014, 00001402, D, Asterisk, IP '' on IP watch list with 4 potential intrusion attempts
Sun Jun 22 14:23:27 2014, 00000510, S, Asterisk, Detected excessive intrustion attempts by username '%40' at IP '' using protocol 'SIP' through security log '/var/log/asterisk/messages'.  Requesting ban.
Sun Jun 22 14:23:27 2014, 00000902, D, ThreatInfo, Adding IP address  to banned IP list
Sun Jun 22 14:23:27 2014, 00000608, S, EventQueue, Banning detected IP  as managed
Sun Jun 22 14:23:27 2014, 00000710, E, SystemCommand, Failed to add rule to iptables chain.  Run result 0; exitcode 2
 :
 :
Sun Jun 22 14:24:08 2014, 00001402, D, Asterisk, IP '' on IP watch list with 5 potential intrusion attempts
Sun Jun 22 14:24:08 2014, 00000510, S, Asterisk, Detected excessive intrustion attempts by username '%40' at IP '' using protocol 'SIP' through security log '/var/log/asterisk/messages'.  Requesting ban.
Sun Jun 22 14:24:08 2014, 00000900, D, ThreatInfo, Ignoring attempt to add duplicate IP  to banned IP list
Sun Jun 22 14:25:28 2014, 00001402, D, Asterisk, IP '' on IP watch list with 6 potential intrusion attempts
Sun Jun 22 14:25:28 2014, 00000510, S, Asterisk, Detected excessive intrustion attempts by username '%40' at IP '' using protocol 'SIP' through security log '/var/log/asterisk/messages'.  Requesting ban.
Sun Jun 22 14:25:28 2014, 00000900, D, ThreatInfo, Ignoring attempt to add duplicate IP  to banned IP list
Sun Jun 22 14:35:36 2014, 00001405, D, Asterisk, IP '' removed from IP watch list due to expiration
```

Note that the reference to IP '', where no actual IP address is shown. It seems that this empty IP reference is causing failure when attempting to add the rule to the iptables chain. Also, attempts to add this to the database seem to be failing (lines omitted above).

Perhaps this indicates that the case of IP '' should be detected to avoid invalid attempts to call upon iptables and the database.

The following are the lines from /var/log/asterisk/messages (with our IP address replaced with IP_REMOVED) that correspond to the events above:

```
[Jun 22 14:22:45] NOTICE[7420] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:%40102@IP_REMOVED>' failed for '176.58.69.112:14398' - Wrong password
[Jun 22 14:22:48] NOTICE[7420][C-0000005a] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device <sip:%40102@IP_REMOVED>;tag=17280b03
[Jun 22 14:22:55] NOTICE[7420][C-0000005b] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device <sip:%40102@IP_REMOVED>;tag=394a4856
[Jun 22 14:23:01] NOTICE[7420][C-0000005c] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device <sip:%40102@IP_REMOVED>;tag=022a0438
[Jun 22 14:23:05] NOTICE[7420] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:%40102@IP_REMOVED>' failed for '176.58.69.112:14398' - Wrong password
[Jun 22 14:23:07] NOTICE[7420] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:%40@IP_REMOVED>' failed for '176.58.69.112:14398' - Wrong password
[Jun 22 14:23:09] NOTICE[7420][C-0000005d] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device <sip:%40@IP_REMOVED>;tag=93209c36
[Jun 22 14:23:12] NOTICE[7420][C-0000005e] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device <sip:%40@IP_REMOVED>;tag=cf5b9246
[Jun 22 14:23:13] NOTICE[7420][C-0000005f] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device <sip:%40@IP_REMOVED>;tag=ae0ff835
[Jun 22 14:23:27] NOTICE[7420] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:%40@IP_REMOVED>' failed for '176.58.69.112:14398' - Wrong password
[Jun 22 14:24:08] NOTICE[7420] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:%40@IP_REMOVED>' failed for '176.58.69.112:14398' - Wrong password
[Jun 22 14:24:21] NOTICE[7420][C-00000060] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device 201<sip:201@IP_REMOVED>;tag=ba38c3c8
[Jun 22 14:25:28] NOTICE[7420] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:%40@IP_REMOVED>' failed for '176.58.69.112:14398' - Wrong password
```

Given what I read from this, I would have expected the IP 176.58.69.112 to have been banned.

Why would the case of IP '' occur, and what steps would remedy this?

**** Update ****

The following messages were observed today in /var/log/secast:

```
2014-06-27T09:43:23, 00001403, D, Asterisk, IP '5.11.41.130' added to watch list
2014-06-27T09:43:23, 00000510, I, Asterisk, Detected potential intrustion attempt by username '1000' at IP '5.11.41.130' using protocol 'SIP' through security log '/var/log/asterisk/messages'
2014-06-27T09:43:43, 00001402, D, Asterisk, IP '5.11.41.130' on IP watch list with 2 potential intrusion attempts
2014-06-27T09:43:43, 00000510, I, Asterisk, Detected potential intrustion attempt by username '1000' at IP '5.11.41.130' using protocol 'SIP' through security log '/var/log/asterisk/messages'
2014-06-27T09:53:52, 00001405, D, Asterisk, IP '5.11.41.130' removed from IP watch list due to expiration
```

These resulted from the following lines in /var/log/asterisk/messages:

```
[Jun 27 09:43:23] NOTICE[1309] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:1000@69.165.131.4>' failed for '5.11.41.130:12736' - Wrong password
[Jun 27 09:43:43] NOTICE[1309] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:1000@69.165.131.4>' failed for '5.11.41.130:12736' - Wrong password
```

While there was an insufficient number of attempts to cause a ban to occur, it does appear that the IP address 5.11.41.130 was picked up as expected. Had there been more attempts, I'd guess that the ban attempt would have been successful this time.

Note that this time the username was simply '1000'; whereas, before the username was: '%40102' and '%40'

Is it possible that the % character was tripping up the secast parsing of the Asterisk messages line, causing the extraction of the IP address to fail?

I'll continue to monitor the logs for an actual ban event and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attacker at 176.58.69.112 is spacing out his connection attempts to avoid detection.  Be sure you set the maxintrusioninterval high enough to see multiple attempts, and maxintrusions set low enough to trigger the detection in that interval.  Can you post your settings from the [credentials] stanza of secast.conf ?  (or email the entire config file to support@generationd.com)

We are seeing more VoIP hackers spacing their attacks out to avoid detection - some even waiting a day or more between attempts.  (We already increased the maximum value of the detection interval settings from 1 hour to 1 week to address this).

The '' IP related messages is a warning that SecAst found something in the asterisk messages file that it could not interpret.  (We will put a more intelligent message in someday)  We received your log file and will run it through our parser and add proper detection for that problematic line.  (Digium makes small changes to log formats regularly, and we are always testing the most recent Asterisk builds against our test scripts to catch these).

** Update: As of SecAst version 1.0.6 those messages are now added to the signature database.

Comment: I have emailed you the entire [credentials] stanza from /etc/xdg/generationd/secast.conf as you requested. The values maxintrusioninterval=600 and maxintrusions=3 are unmodified from the values in the sample config file secast-1.0.6.0-x86_64-ub12/secast.conf. To me, based on the output above, the problem observed doesn't seem to be that attacker eluded detection by secast. (continued...)

Comment: Instead, it seems that secast did correctly identify an intrusion attempt, but it failed to parse the IP address 176.58.69.112 from the lines in /var/log/asterisk/messages. I believe this can be seen by the attempt to add a rule to iptables in the line "SystemCommand, Failed to add rule to iptables chain.  Run result 0; exitcode 2". I think that indicates that an invalid IP address reference was used in that attempt to ban. Hopefully this can be resolved by running my /var/log/asterisk/messages file I email through secast in your development environment.

Comment: Could you try v1.0.6 to see if the problem remains?  That will help determine if the problem is a missing IP or a intrusion interval issue.

Comment: Yes, I'll watch the logs and report back once I see relevant activity. Thanks.

Comment: Please see the first update to the question with the latest observations of the log files. As mentioned, note that this time the username was simply '1000' (a case where the IP address was successfully extracted); whereas, before the username was: '%40102' and '%40'. Is it possible that the % character was tripping up the secast parsing of the Asterisk messages line, causing the extraction of the IP address to fail?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (I can't see the actual code change) but from what I see in the developer notes something on the line prevented detection.  The % seems likely since I'm not sure I've seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that hackers/scanners are also reducing their brute force attempts to even just a single attempt every day (again to avoid detection).  If you wanted to tighten your security you could reduce the max intrusions to 1, and expand the interval to 2 days or more.  (That is why the attack shown in your logs likely stops at 2 attempts).

Based on systems we monitor through support contracts, we see hackers from Palestine and Africa are doing this a lot.  They are trying to stay under the radar or intrusion detection systems.

An alternative (and more proactive way to block them) is to use the Geo IP fencing built into SecAst, and block the entire country/continent where these attacks are coming from.  Check out [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/597257/blocking-geographic-cities-from-accessing-asterisk-using-secast) for more info.

Comment: I am taking your advice on both fronts. My purchase request for the SecAst license has been submitted, and I'll set up geofencing as soon as the license is in place. Thanks.